# C program I would like to know if there's anyway to simplify my dayofyear program?

Tags: c, unix

I am new to C and I wrote this C program that gets the user to input the day of the year and in return the program will output the month and what day of the month it falls on. The program runs fine, but I would like to simplify the program now. I understand the I would need a loop but I am not sure how to go about it. Here is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day);

int main() {
int month[13] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int year, dayofyear, *day;

printf("Enter the day of the year: ");
scanf("%d", &dayofyear);
printf("Enter the year: ");
scanf("%d", &year);
printf("Day %d of year %d falls on:\n ",dayofyear, year);

SplitDate(dayofyear, year, month, day);

}

void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day)
{
if(dayofyear >=1 && dayofyear <= 31)
    {
      printf("month = 1    day = %d\n",dayofyear);
    }
  else if(dayofyear >=32 && dayofyear <= 59)
    {
      printf("month = 2   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 31);
    }
  else if(dayofyear >=60 && dayofyear <=90)
    {
      printf("month = 3  day = %d\n", dayofyear - 59);
    }
  else if(dayofyear >=91 && dayofyear <=120)
   {
     printf("month = 4   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 90);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=121 && dayofyear <=151)
   {
     printf("month = 5   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 120);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=151 && dayofyear <=180)
   {
     printf("month = 6   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 150);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=181 && dayofyear <=211)
   {
     printf("month = 7   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 180);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=212 && dayofyear <=242)
   {
     printf("month = 8   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 211);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=243 && dayofyear <=272)
   {
     printf("month = 9   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 242);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=273 && dayofyear <=303)
   {
     printf("month = 10    day = %d\n", dayofyear -272 );
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=304 && dayofyear <=333)
   {
     printf("month = 11   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 303);
   }
  else if(dayofyear >=334 && dayofyear <=364)
   {
     printf("month = 12   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 333);
   }
}
```

Comment: First, fix your endless recursion (and ambiguous function) and read up on leap years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day){
    static int months[13] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    //months[2] : Requires a correction of leap year
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=12;++i){
        if(dayofyear > months[i]){
            dayofyear -= months[i];
        } else {
            printf("month = %d\t day = %d\n", i, dayofyear);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the C standard library `<time.h>` header, especially `ctime()` and `asctime()`.  Learn how to use them.